# Using Async/Await with Array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await

So I know that async/await will not work with map. I am just returning my request and using `Promise.all()` to execute them. My question is that I have other promises inside and was wondering if the `Promise.all()` will also execute those inside the map in the correct order.

Here is the code:

```js
const productImageIds = Object.keys(data.webImages)

        for(let i = productImageIds.length; i--;){
            const productId = productImageIds[i]
            const images = data.webImages[productId]
            const requests = images.map(async (image, i) => {
                const name = `${productId}_${i}.${image.split(`.`).pop()}`
                const imageStream = await downloadImage(image, name) // IS THIS WORKING CORRECTLY WITH USING PROMISE.ALL() ??
                const res =  sanityRequest({
                    ...sanityConfig,
                    type: `images`,
                    endpoint: `assets`,
                    contentType: `image/jpeg`,
                    body: imageStream,
                params: `?filename=${name}`,
                })


                    await unlinkSync(name) // IS THIS WORKING CORRECTLY WITH USING PROMISE.ALL() ??
                    return res

            })

            const uploadedImages = await Promise.all(requests)
        }
```

Comment: Concurrent Promises are never executed in a given order. `Promise.all` resolves when all Promises end, whatever their order.

Comment: Just a quick note. You might want to change `for(let i = productImageIds.length; i--;){` to be `for(let i = productImageIds.length-1; i--;){` to avoid accessing out of bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is that I have other promises inside and was wondering if the Promise.all() will also execute those inside the map in the correct order.

No.

`Promise.all()` will create a promise which resolves when all the promises passed to it resolve. It has no influence over what order those promises resolve in (and couldn't because they will have started running before `Promise.all` is invoked).

If you want to deal with each value of `images` *in sequence* (rather than in parallel) then use a regular `for` loop.